# Using SendGrid PHP API in Wordpress without Composer

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

The title mainly says it all but I'm at a loss as to how I should use the SendGrid php library without Composer in Wordpress. It's not as simple as the [SendGrid github readme.md](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/README.md) makes it out to be:

```
// If you are not using Composer
// require("path/to/sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php");
```

This is because sendgrid-php.php contains the following:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
?>
```

So even if you aren't calling autoload.php yourself, the sendgrid file is.

Is there a way to use the library without composer? Because composer does not work with Wordpress (except through some janky workarounds).

If anyone has experience with this I'd love to hear your thoughts.

Thanks.

Comment: Why you can't just load `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` in your functions.php?

Comment: When I tried it doesn't work. I'm new to Composer so I'm not sure if this is true, but from reading around the web Composer does not play nice with Wordpress unless you try some hacky methods.

Answer (score 1):

If u don't want to use composer. Try to download the package [here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/archive/master.zip). Then extract the lib folder to your (child) theme. Then in your `functions.php` add this code:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/lib/loader.php');
// Use Send grid right here...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have it running now by pulling all the classes and files out myself and requiring them individually in my functions.php but this looks much cleaner. I'll have a go and let you know how it goes. Thanks again.